# List Azure blobs in a ListBox in a WPF App

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, listbox, azure-blob-storage

I have a ListBox in a WPF Application where I want to list out all the Blobs I have stored in Azure. The code below is what I'm currently trying but to no success.

Code from xaml.cs

```
 public ObservableCollection<string> Blobs = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        const string StorrageAccountName = "****";
        const string StorageAccountKey = "****==";

        var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(
        new Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(StorrageAccountName, StorageAccountKey), true);


        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("****");


        var description = string.Empty;

        foreach (IListBlobItem item in container.ListBlobs(null, false))
        {
            if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
            {
                CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
                description = $"Block blob of length {blob.Properties.Length}: {blob.Uri}";
            }
            else if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudPageBlob))
            {
                CloudPageBlob pageBlob = (CloudPageBlob)item;
                description = $"Page blob of length {pageBlob.Properties.Length}: {pageBlob.Uri}";
            }
            else if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlobDirectory))
            {
                CloudBlobDirectory directory = (CloudBlobDirectory)item;
                description = $"Directory: {directory.Uri}";
            }

            Blobs.Add(description);
        }
    }
```

Code changed from .xaml

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Blobs}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="323" Grid.RowSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="267" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" Margin="0,-4,0,0" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  />
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be creating an observable collection of the blob's list and binding it to the list box? All you're doing right now is printing on console.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you are just writing your descriptions out to the console, not to your WPF view.

You need to add your descriptions to an ObservableCollection which the View can bind to

Change your code to

```
//This is the collection containing your descriptions
public ObservableCollection<string> Blobs = new ObservableCollection<string>();

private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

    const string StorrageAccountName = "****";
    const string StorageAccountKey = "*****==";

    var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(
        new Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(StorrageAccountName, StorageAccountKey), true);



    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("***");


    var description = string.Empty;

    foreach (IListBlobItem item in container.ListBlobs(null, false))
    {
        if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
        {
            CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
            description = $"Block blob of length {blob.Properties.Length}: {blob.Uri}";
        }
        else if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudPageBlob))
        {
            CloudPageBlob pageBlob = (CloudPageBlob)item;
            description = $"Page blob of length {pageBlob.Properties.Length}: {pageBlob.Uri}";
        }
        else if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlobDirectory))
        {
            CloudBlobDirectory directory = (CloudBlobDirectory)item;
            description = $"Directory: {directory.Uri}";
        }

        // add your descriptions to the collection
        Blobs.Add(description);
    }
}
```

And change your ListControl to

```
<ListControl ItemsSource="{Binding Blobs}" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've edited my code based on your answer but I can't get it working. Am I missing something?